# Js infinte marquee text. Works on mouseover, but not on doc load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a strange problem. I have digged up this code snippet that allows a text row to be animated left and then repeated infinitely. While this works perfectly. I'd like to have **all the rows to be animated on body load** but much slower. And then when you mouseover on each of the rows the animation picks up more speed.

**https://codepen.io/umbriel/pen/RjYqRR**

So far I've tried stuff like looping each of the questions and then running the animation. But it still only grabbed one of the divs and animated it.

```
var el_text = questions[i].querySelectorAll('.intro-question-text');

for (var i = 0; i < el_text.length; i++) {
  el_text[i].style.transform = 'translate3d(' + qScrollPositions[i] + 'px,0,0)'
}
```

Any pointers? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it to do what you want by using the setInterval function (and swapping it out to a quicker one when the user hovers over the element).

```js
var textCopy = document.querySelectorAll('.intro-question-text')
for (var i = 0; i < textCopy.length; i++) {
  var text = textCopy[i].innerHTML.repeat(5)
  textCopy[i].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', text)
}

var WIN_H,
    WIN_W,
    qFrame = [];

var questions = document.querySelectorAll('.intro-question');
var scrollRequest;
var qScrollPositions = [];
var passiveRepeaters = [];
var repeater;

function initIntroScript() {
  Array.prototype.map.call(questions, function(q, i) {
    addImageHover(i);
  })
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
  resizeHandler();
}

function addImageHover(i) {
  qFrame[i] = 0;
  qScrollPositions[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * -200);
  questions[i].querySelector('.intro-question-text').style.transform = 'translate3d(' + qScrollPositions[i] + 'px,0,0)';
  questions[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    //console.log("mouseenter -> " + i);
    clearInterval(passiveRepeaters[i]);
    repeater = setInterval(function() {
      scrollQuestionText(i);
    }, 10);
  });
  
  questions[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    //console.log("mouseleave -> " + i);
    clearInterval(repeater);
    passiveRepeaters[i] = setInterval(function() {
      scrollQuestionText(i);
    }, 20);
  });
  
  passiveRepeaters[i] = setInterval(function() {
   scrollQuestionText(i);
  }, 20);
}

function scrollQuestionText(i) {
  var shift = Math.floor(4 + WIN_W/800) * Math.min(0.2, qFrame[i] / 20);
  cancelAnimationFrame(scrollRequest);
  var el_text = questions[i].querySelector('.intro-question-text');
  qScrollPositions[i] = qScrollPositions[i] - shift;
  if (qScrollPositions[i] < -el_text.clientWidth / 2 - 5) {
    qScrollPositions[i] = 0;
  }
  el_text.style.transform = 'translate3d(' + qScrollPositions[i] + 'px,0,0)'
  qFrame[i]++;
}

initIntroScript();

function resizeHandler() { // NEEDS TO NOT BREAK ON RESIZE
  WIN_W = window.innerWidth;
  WIN_H = window.innerHeight;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size:4rem;
}
.intro-question {
    position: relative;
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    will-change: transform, color, background;
    flex-shrink: 2;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    transition: opacity .5s, transform 1s ease-out;
    z-index: 2;
}
.intro-question-text {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    will-change: transform;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: .5s opacity;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-questions">
  <div class="intro-question">
    <div class="intro-question-text white">
      Testing content in here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="intro-question">
    <div class="intro-question-text white">
      Content testing
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="intro-question">
    <div class="intro-question-text white">
      Content stackoverflow please
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

**edit**

You can increase the framerate by reducing the interval between the function calls, for example

```
  questions[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    //console.log("mouseenter -> " + i);
    clearInterval(passiveRepeaters[i]);
    repeater = setInterval(function() {
      scrollQuestionText(i);
    }, 10);
  });

  questions[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    //console.log("mouseleave -> " + i);
    clearInterval(repeater);
    passiveRepeaters[i] = setInterval(function() {
      scrollQuestionText(i);
    }, 20);
  });

  passiveRepeaters[i] = setInterval(function() {
    scrollQuestionText(i);
  }, 20);
```

if you do this and don't want the scrolling to speed up you can decrease the step size like this

```
var shift = Math.floor(4 + WIN_W/800) * Math.min(0.2, qFrame[i] / 10);
```

Comment: Very interesting approach for this challange. Thank you for helping out. Is there a way to reduce the choppiness? Even when I only have 1 row animating, the framerate is really low. Any pointers? Thank you

Comment: @SebastianGraz I edited the answer - it's choppy because the interval is too long (you can see it stop between functions) - you can decrease the interval and step, and it should look a lot smoother

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: No problem :) !